# Find all triples positive integers $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy the equation $2(x+y+z+2xyz)^2=(2xy+2xz+2yz+1)^2+2023$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As the question stated above: $2(x+y+z+2xyz)^2=(2xy+2xz+2yz+1)^2+2023$

I tried to expand both sides of the equation and simplify, I get

$x^2+ y^2 + z^2 + 4x^2y^2z^2=2x^2y^2+2y^2z^2+2x^2z^2 + 1012$

After that, I did trial-error, and I get $(2,3,3)$ as solution. How do we make sure, that that there is (if any) other solution? If no other solution exists, how do we make sure of that?

Comment: I don't get it, how can I get that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG let $x\le y\le z$.

You have found that $$x^2+y^2+z^2+4x^2y^2z^2=2x^2y^2+2y^2z^2+2z^2z^2+1012$$
So,$$2x^2+2y^2+2z^2+8x^2y^2z^2=4x^2y^2+4y^2z^2+4z^2z^2+2024\\8x^2y^2z^2-4x^2y^2-4y^2z^2-4z^2x^2+2x^2+2y^2+2z^2-1=2023\\(2x^2-1)(2y^2-1)(2z^2-1)=2023$$
$x$, $y$ and $z$ are positive integers so $2x^2-1$, $2y^2-1$ and $2z^2-1$ are positive integers, and $(2x^2-1,2y^2-1,2z^2-1)$ is a factor triple of $2023$.

Since $x\le y\le z$, $2x^2-1\le2y^2-1\le2z^2-1$. Then, $$(2x^2-1,2y^2-1,2z^2-1)=(1,1,2023),(1,7,289),(1,17,119),(7,17,17)$$
The only triple of $(x,y,z)$ that works are $$(x,y,z)=(2,3,3)$$ and its different arrangements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the equation rewrites as
$$(2x^2 - 1)(2y^2 - 1)(2z^2 - 1) = 2023.$$

Can you continue the argument?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thank you. This is what I need.